# unable to connect to remote mysql server aws

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, firewall, remote-server

I woke up this morning and my frontend server could no longer connect to my mysql server. I have no idea why:

The internal ip of my frontend server is `172.31.X.X`.

My db server is configured with firewall inbound rules that allow tcp connections on port `3306` via source `172.31.0.0/16`

My frontend server is configured with firewall outbound rules that allow tcp connections on port `3306` to the internal ip address of my db server.

The mysql user I use is `mysql_prod`. These are the privileges I have granted for that user on the db server:

mysql> show grants for mysql_prod;

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mysql_prod@%                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysql_prod'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*5B761DF55A90C1E168EC63A3B074A607ECC3B2CA' |

| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `wordpress`.* TO 'mysql_prod'@'%'                                                          |

What am I missing?

Comment: So, you are able to connect, but the front-end isn't? Can you find a complete error message in the front-end server logs, describing the failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurred because the mysql `bind-address` was set to localhost, which prevented remote connections. I'm not too sure how this conf got reset (the app was working fine the night before). Anyways, once I fixed it, it was working fine.